# How can I determine what key is being used by an SSH command?

Tags: shell, ssh

## Background

I have an Jenkins server that we use for enterprise job scheduling.  I have a job that runs the following shell script

```
#!/bin/bash -xe

ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=10 insidetk@albrl1 "Rscript /home/insidetk/PRIORITIZATION/Analytics_Modal.R"
```

As you can see the ssh command doesn't specify an IdentityFile.  Therefore I deduce that it must be using a key stored in a known_host file.

On the box where this script is running I see there are keys in the `$HOME/.ssh/known_host` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` files.  However, there are literally thousands of keys in these files from thousands of different jobs.

## Attempts

In the aforementioned files I have attempted to search for the user *insidetk*, the ip address of the box, the hostname of the box, etc in hopes of finding the key in these files.  However those strings don't appear in these files.

I cant find the SSH logs anywhere and I don't have journalctl installed

## Question

How can I identify the key that is being used by this ssh command?

Comment: `IdentityFile` refers to the user's private key, while `known_hosts` on the client lists the public keys of known remote hosts: are you looking for the key that is used for authenticating the user on the remote host or the key the client uses to make sure it already knows the `albrl1` host?

Comment: Im looking for the key that is used to authenticate the user on the remote host

Comment: Use the `-v` option on `ssh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable `ssh`'s verbose output, running (interactively):

```bsh
ssh -v insidetk@albrl1
```

You should then be able to spot lines that look like

```
debug1: Offering public key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:<key's fingerprint>
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:<key's fingerprint>
```

Comment: Gave me the exact line.  Ty